# Maximizing $\dfrac{4 \sqrt{a} + 6 \sqrt{b} + 12 \sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{abc}}$ over $a+b+c=4abc$ and $a,b,c>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,$ $b,$ $c$ be positive real numbers such that $a + b + c = 4abc.$ Find the maximum value of
$$\dfrac{4 \sqrt{a} + 6 \sqrt{b} + 12 \sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{abc}}.$$

---

First, I tried using $\dfrac{4 \sqrt{a} + 6 \sqrt{b} + 12 \sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{abc}}=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{bc}}+\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{ac}}+\dfrac{12}{\sqrt{ab}}$. Then, I tried to apply some inequalities, but it didn't work.

I also tried just substituting $abc=\dfrac{a+b+c}{4}$ into the equation, but this also didn't do much. Could someone give me some guidance on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Use lagrange multipliers

Comment: And, what inequalities did you try?

Comment: Hmm... What are Lagrange multipliers? I tried using inequalities like QM-AM.

Comment: Tl;dr:  Method for multivariable optimization under constraint . [Video reply](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js277PnBccI)

Comment: You should add your attempt and wdhat you got when you tried those inequalities @Mathmagician . It maybe that from where you got stuck, there is a way to reach solution that you don't see (which someone else answering could tell you)

Comment: One thing that should make it substantially easier: divide both sides of the constraint by $abc$ to get $\frac1{bc}+\frac1{ac}+\frac1{ab}=4$. Now you can do a change of variables $x=\frac1{\sqrt{bc}}$, $y=\frac1{\sqrt{ac}}$, $z=\frac1{\sqrt{ab}}$. (First prove that we can recover $a, b, c$ from $x, y, z$ so this is a one-to-one mapping!) What form does the constraint take in terms of this $x,y,z$? What does the function to optimize look like? Do you know how to optimize that sort of function subject to that constraint?

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Yes, thanks. Just easy Cauchy. :)